# Infopath Browser form Ribbon modification

Tags: infopath, ribbon

How we can customize sharepoint 2010 form server ribbon buttons? I found 'Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathHomeTab' in page source but it seems that we can't add ribbon button to this location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this blog might answer your question:

http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/03/add-custom-commands-on-infopath-browser-form-ribbon/